# Method of cylindrical shell in James Stewart calculus

Tags: calculus, integration

I want to know my error.

In James Stewart Calculus, there is the method of cylindrical shell.
(Chapter 6.3, 8 ed)

they derives the cylinder's volume as follows:

(I am sorry that I cannot draw the picture)

$V = V_2 - V_1 $

$\space\space\space= \pi r^2_2h - \pi r^2_1h$ ($r_2$ is outer radius, $r_1$ is inner radius)

$\space\space\space= \pi (r^2_2 -  r^2_1)h$

$\space\space\space= \pi (r_2 +  r_1)(r_2-r_1)h$

$\space\space\space= \pi (r_2 +  r_1)\Delta rh$

$\space\space\space= 2\pi r\Delta rh$ ($\color{red}{r = \frac{1}{2}(r_2+r_1)}$)

But as I know, we can choose any point $r$ such as $ r_1\le r \le r_2 $.

Why we should put $r$ like the red part?

If I put the $r = \frac{2}{3}(r_2+r_1)$, then the result of volume is different.

Comment: What you 'know' is wrong.  Different values of r will obviously give different values of the volume.  The specific value r= (r1+ r2)/2 is from the "r1+ r2" already in the formula. What **is** true is that as you take r2 going to r1, then all "r" between r2 and r1 go to the same thing- but you haven't done that yet.